# Accessing a node.js Hapi server running inside a docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, boot2docker, hapi.js

I have built a docker container from centOS using a node.js hapi server. The server works fine running on its own, I get the right output in the console when running it inside the container. However, I don't know how to get at it.

Output from docker container

```
$ docker run -p 49000:3000 work/learning
Server running at: http://f878541bb9f8:3000
Pack Server running at:  http://f878541bb9f8:5000
```

Docker file

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 0.3.4
FROM centos:centos6
# Enable EPEL for Node.js
RUN     rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# Install Node.js and npm
RUN     yum install -y npm

ADD . /src
RUN cd src; npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node /src/server.js
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'get at it'?  Does curling localhost:49000 not work?

Comment: Yes, I mean access via http request. No, can't get anything from localhost:49000

Comment: So when you curl 3000 from inside the container you get something, but not from outside at 49000.  Correct?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue. I used your Dockerfile + npm init + npm install hapi --save + the server.js file from http://hapijs.com/tutorials. I'm able to see the 'Hello world' response using `curl http://localhost:49000/`

Comment: Are you by any change using boot to docker? If so the container will expose ports on ```192.168.59.103``` not localhost

Comment: @Usman Yes, this was my problem. Thanks. I can access the server with 192.168.59.103:49000